# Certificate of http-toolkit proxy is not trusted in iOS browser

Tags: http-toolkit

I followed all the instructions in https://httptoolkit.com/docs/guides/ios/

I installed the configuration profile on my iPhone.
I can visit https://amiusing.httptoolkit.tech/ with Safari on my iPhone and it displays the webpage saying that my traffic is intercepted.
However when I visit any other https website in Safari I get a warning page saying "This connection is not private". Also no app is working. On the HTTP Toolkit View page I see all the requests but with "Aborted connection to..."

What am I doing wrong?
Using an iPhone 15 with latest iOS 17.3.1

Comment: Hmm, that's very unusual! Have you definitely enabled "Full trust" in the iOS settings? Do you have any other security features, VPNs, or other security restrictions enabled that might affect this?